# HTTPS crawling issue with Nutch

Tags: ssl, web-crawler, nutch

He guy i want to crawl https sites using nutch 1.9 with java7

in seed.txt

```
https://site.com
```

in regex-urlfilter.txt

```
+^https://([a-z0-9]*\.)*site.com/
```

but when running crawlig process using `bin/crawl ...` i got a **javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for crawling the website which has default certificate and i hope this may help others people who will encounter this problem.

Some Post in this forum mentionned about adding argument `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`
but where to put that?
I edited the nucth file using nano and added this argument in **NUTCH_OPTS**
in nutch 1.9 it is on  line 195 which is now

```
NUTCH_OPTS=($NUTCH_OPTS -Dhadoop.log.dir="$NUTCH_LOG_DIR" -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false)
```

after that the crawling got success without breaking